# Array out of bounds, error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which copies emails from an inbox, pastes them into a workbook, transposes that info to another sheet, clears the first sheet then should loop to the next email.

It works fine for 1 email but when there are 2 or more emails I get a debug error saying array out of bounds?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

```
Sub EmailText()
Dim ObjOutlook As Object
Dim MyNamespace As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim abody() As String
Set ObjOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set MyNamespace = ObjOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
For i = 1 To MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST").Items.Count
    abody = Split(MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST").Items(i).Body, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
    For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
        Sheet1.Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = abody(j)
    Next
    MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST2")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Dim NextRow As Range
            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                Set NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("E2:E7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2:A20").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B8").Select
Next
Set ObjOutlook = Nothing
Set MyNamespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Many Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I guess when you move your item `MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST2")` to another folder, Items count changed. Try to use reverse loop: `For i = MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TEST").Items.Count To 1 Step -1`

Comment: A couple of side observations: (i) I would use `Long` rather than `Integer` as the latter gives an error after 32,767 items. (ii) You do not need to `Set` your objects to `Nothing` as they are killed automatically at this point. (iii) It is a good practice to avoid using `select`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: Great feedback @loannis I will take a look at the thread you suggested and bare that in mind. Thanks!